# codeigniter modular seperation problem php mvc

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok so Im running 1.7.2 and I installed the codeigniter-modular-seperation library (the newest version which is maintained by Phil Sturgeon , as the wiki said to install that version if Im using 1.7 or above)

-- anyways, the documentation is super light, just says put MY_Router and MY_Loader in the libraries folder which Ive done, and everything is working as far as the module urls go, but when I try and make the modules talk to each other as per both of the following articles:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC/

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC

but I get

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Modules::run() in *siteurl*  on line 4

I also tried loading the module like this

[code]load->module('ratings/ratings'); ?> [/code]

which yields an error Call to undefined method MY_Loader::module()

So ya, anyone have any idea how to fix this? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

soooooooo, correct me if Im wrong, but, it appears that the newer version of HMVC (the one you are advised to download if you use 1.7+), does not support cross loading of controllers. I switched to the old version and its working perfect, although I have to say Im not sure I understand the purpose of making it modular, if you aren’t able to cross load from other controllers (unless you are just using the modules to create completely separate unique webpages by using each directory as its own mini codeigniter installation.

I replaced the new with the old version and its working perfect.

Phil, if you read this, do you have any plans to implement cross controller/resource loading in a future version? Because (and I mean no disrespect you know a hell of a ton more about php than me), it seems like the whole power behind the Zend framework is its modularity. The problem I have with Zend is its honestly the most confusing shit I have ever attempted to understand (I have an ecommerce store running on magento), but even though its confusing and frustrating as all hell, its absolutely brilliant because of how extendable it is. I feel like if CI were more modular (without hacking it up all over), it would have 2000x the power as it does now.